# Named export with same name as existing variable in Javascript ES Modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

For technical reasons [detailed here (CJS)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions?gen=2nd#write_functions_in_multiple_files) I need to import a function and then reexport it immediately. The linked doc explains how to do this in CJS, but how can I do the same in ES Modules?

My code below shows an error:

```
import { foo } from './foo';
import { bar } from './bar';

export const foo = foo;
export const bar = bar;
```

Error: `Parsing error: Identifier 'foo' has already been declared`

For reference, Common JS code that works and that I am trying to convert to ESM:

```
const foo = require('./foo');
const bar = require('./bar');
exports.foo = foo.foo;
exports.bar = bar.bar;
```

Comment: `export {foo} from "./foo"`    or  `export {foo}`  if you already have it as an import.

Comment: `export const foo = foo;` is short for `const foo = foo; export { foo as foo }`. Ditch the local `const`, you already have an import.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `export` keyword:

```
export { foo } from './foo'
```

Check https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/barrel

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *reexport*:

```
export { foo } from './foo'
```

If you want to *import and then export*:

```
import { foo } from './foo'
doWhatever(foo)
export { foo }
```

If you want *import and make export const with same name*:

```
import { foo as importedFoo } from './foo'
export const foo = doWhatever(importedFoo)
```